# Nodemailer /send gives 404 error

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404, nodemailer

I'm trying to use [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) to send a message from a standard website form to an email address. I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CL1sit7wAV4&index=1&list=PLDbt-8dyNTUWHVgSOMthRpzwF7A2ATMzG) and everything works on the local server. But when I upload the documentation to my hosting provider I get the following error:

> POST http://mydomain.rs/send 404 (Not Found)
>
> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /send was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an 
>     ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have three files relevant to the nodemailer, those are:

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

// Home page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
    //console.log 
    console.log('NodeMailer reading console log...' + req.url);

});

// sending mail function
app.post('/send', function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.email == "" || req.body.subject == "") {
        res.send("Error: Email & Subject should not blank");
        return false;
    }

    // Sending Emails with SMTP, Configuring SMTP settings

    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
        host: "mail.mydomain.rs", // hostname
        secureConnection: true, // use SSL
        port: 465, // port for secure SMTP
        auth: {
            user: 'messages@mydomain.rs',
            pass: 'password'
        },
        proxy: 'http://mydomain.rs:' + port
    });
    var mailOptions = {
        from: "Node Emailer ✔ <messages@mydomain.rs>", // sender address
        to: req.body.emailto, // list of receivers
        subject: req.body.subject + " ✔", // Subject line
        //text: "Hello world ✔", // plaintext body
        html: "<b>" + req.body.description + "</b>" // html body
    }
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            res.send("Email could not sent due to error: " + error);
        } else {
            res.send("Email has been sent successfully");
        }
    });
});

// Starting server
    var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, function () {
        console.log("Server is Running on 127.0.0.1:" + port);
    });
```

the part of the index page relevant to the form:

index.html

```
        <form role="form" id="emailForm" method="post">
            <div class="form_content">
                <h2>KONTAKTIRAJTE&nbsp;NAS</h2>
                <p id="msg"></p>
                <input type="text" name="ime" placeholder="IME" required="required" />
                <input type="tel" name="telefon" placeholder="TELEFON" />
                <p class="mini_text">
                    Otvoreni od 8h - 17h
                    <br> Zatvoreni vikendom osim za posebne usluge
                </p>
                <input type="email" name="emailto" value="myactualemail@gmail.com" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required="required" />
                <textarea name="description" placeholder="PORUKA" required="required"></textarea>
                <button id="send" type="button">POŠALJI</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

and the package.json

```
{
  "name": "speednodemailers",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "NodeJs email form to send email using nodejs",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.13.3",
    "express": "^3.21.2",
    "node-mailer": "^0.1.1",
    "nodemailer": "^0.7.1"
  }
}
```

So as I mentioned everything works perfectly on localhost, the problem occurs when I upload the project to my hosting provider.

Is there a step to the upload that I am missing?
Or a setting that I overlooked?
Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated as I am somewhat of a beginner at back-end stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi , did you solve this error ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? @igor